# Why is the group of translations normal in the Affine group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

So I understand the construction of this semi-direct product and it's properties. However I am confused to why $K^n$ is normal in Aff(n,K).

My main confusion comes from this. I believe understand how T$_{A,b}$ $\in$Aff(n,K) acts on x$\in$K$^n$.

It would be T$_{A,b}$(x)=Ax+b right?

But how does x act on T$_{A,b}$?

Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: Changed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, vectors are not acting on affine transformations. **Translations** are of the form $x\mapsto x+b$ for vectors $b\in K^n$. These comprise a subgroup of ${\rm Aff}(n,K)$ which is isomorphic to $(K^n,+)$.

Comment: So why can a semidirect product be produced?

Comment: @user139985 If $G$ is a group and $H,N$ subgroups, $G$ is an internal semidirect product when $N$ is normal, $G=NH$ and $H\cap N$. Do you understand why this creates an isomorphism of $G$ with the external semidirect product construction $N\rtimes H$? Can you prove the two subgroups here exhibit the desired properties to make Aff an internal semidirect product? Do some work.

Comment: Ah I get it now. T$_{I,b}$ and T$_{A,0}$ right?

Comment: The subgroups are comprised of those elements respectively, right.

Comment: yeah, thanks it clicked right when you said it and I din't want to MathJax it all out.